# Stored Procedure to a Table with Variable Number of columns

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

How do you insert the output of a SP into a table when the result can have a variable number of columns?

This SP creates a table where the number of columns may vary. I need to put the results into a temp table so I can use it to query reports. How do I create a table that can handle the output of the SP?

```
 DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
 @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX); 

 SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.question) 
        FROM temp_SURVEY_DATA c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

 set @query =  'SELECT responseid, moduleid, responsedatetime, ' + @cols + ' from 
        (select question, response, responsedatetime, responseid, moduleid
            from temp_SURVEY_DATA) x
        pivot 
        ( max(response)
            for question IN(' + @cols + ') ) p '

          execute(@query)
```

Comment: And **what** database and which version??? Those things are most often vendor-specific ...

Comment: I'm using SQL 2005. I've seen the OPENROWSET function and have used SQLNCLI as the provider type, I don't know if that's correct of not. I'm not certain how I find out.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static table dedicated specifically for this kind of thing and insert the result set into it instead of returning the rows to the caller:

```
DECLARE @cols AS VARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX); 

 SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.question) 
        FROM temp_SURVEY_DATA c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'');

EXECUTE ('IF OBJECT_ID(''temp_SURVEY_DATA_pivoted'') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE temp_SURVEY_DATA_pivoted');

set @query =  'SELECT responseid, moduleid, responsedatetime, ' + @cols + '
  INTO temp_SURVEY_DATA_pivoted
  from 
        (select question, response, responsedatetime, responseid, moduleid
            from temp_SURVEY_DATA) x
        pivot 
        ( max(response)
            for question IN(' + @cols + ') ) p '

          execute(@query)
```

Or abandon the idea of dynamic scripting when it is used somewhere else than immediately before displaying your data.